# logged in whatever the password or username is:

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have this code:

```
if($submit)
{
    $first=$_POST['first'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
    mysql_select_db("learndb",$db);
    $sql = "select * from admin where username = '" . $first . "' and password = '". $password . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    if($result>0)
{
    echo "LOGGED IN!!";
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR!!!";
}
```

and my html form is:

```
<form method="post" action="input-copy.php">
First name:<input type="Text" name="first" placeholder="ENTER YOUR NAME"><br>
password:<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="ENTER PASSWORD"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter information"></form>
```

but whatever I enter into firstname and password it displays LOGGED IN!

Comment: use mysql_num_rows == 1 to check and use mysqli or pdo

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan Since your comment will probably solve the issue, why don't you submit it as an answer?

Comment: dont use greater than 0 to check if it's returns more than one row than it's a security issue

Comment: You should not use this in production. Instead **fix that gaping SQL Injection you've left in there**. That will land you in a world of issues if this is a production site.

Comment: @peter posting it as a answer will take some time that's why I posted it as comment so that I can solve his problem quickly

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions - they are deprecated. Switch to mysqli_* functions which are future safe and will offer you prepared statements to easily avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Darren indeed I always say this _I assume you don't want some 12 y/o kid who found a malicious SQL query on Google to ruin your whole database. Because that is what you are facing if you don't use prepared statements when handling user input._ Because there is no reason not to use prepared statements. There is none. It is the same as you don't post all of your passwords and usernames on Facebook.

Comment: "security is not a big deal for me" - then you are probably better off not asking for a password at all.

Comment: You're using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) against. You're using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and should [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of passwords.

Comment: @Quentin just wondering what the error is and i got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your `$result` variable will store [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) return value, this will true if your mySQL query correct. Also this is the reason that your logic will *logged in whatever the password or username is*.

You need to check the result count using [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);//Check database table data exits...
if($num_rows == 1){
 //You stuff here
}
```

**Warning**

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 4):

**[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

Use **[mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)**

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($row > 0) {
    echo "LOGGED IN!!";
} else {
    echo "ERROR!!!";
}
```

**Note**

> Mysql is depricated instead use mysqli or PDO

Don't store plain password into database use hashing technic

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

To prevent from sql injection check **[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple login code that you can try

```
//login query
$sql="SELECT password FROM login WHERE user_name='$username'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 1)
{
    // Associative array
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($password == $row["password"]) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        echo "Loggedin";
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not a valid user";
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["error_log"] = "No such user exist!";
    header("location:../index.php");
    die($_SESSION["error_log"]);
}
```